# OpenGL vertex buffer objects on windows-how run it? qt windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl, vbo

I'm trying to use VBO to create a terrain from a heightmap, but i don't know what should I include to my project or what headers to use. I'm using Qt and my OS is Windows 7. When i want to use glGenBuffers(1, &VboId); it throws an error: "glGenBuffers was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBO is not part of OpenGL core until a specific version and so on. That can make it cumbersome to access it. Most developers use a library like GLEW to resolve the lookup of extensions like VBO.

Another possibility is to use Qt functionality, as described here:
http://entropologygames.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/howto-use-vertex-buffer-objectsvbo-with-opengl-qt/

**In your case however I would suggest you use QGLBuffer** (Qt 4.7 and up), which nicely encapsulates VBO functionality.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglbuffer.html